# Последний день месяца

Tags: javascript

```js
function getLastDayOfMonth(year, month){
    var d = new Date(year, month + 1);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)
    return d
}
console.log(getLastDayOfMonth(2013, 1));
```

Скажите правильно, а то у меня сомнения :(

Comment: в чем сомнения, что 27е число последний день февраля?

Comment: Thu Feb 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Москва, стандартное время)

Comment: @teran а у меня   Thu Feb 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Москва, стандартное время)

Comment: @teran просто сомневаюсь что сделал правильно

Comment: @teran, если сразу делать getDate(), то должно быть нормально. Просто не надо в UTC переводить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо вычитания единицы можно сразу писать 0, а так всё верно.

```js
function getLastDayOfMonth(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
}

console.log("2019: " + Array(12).fill(2019).map(getLastDayOfMonth).join(" "))
console.log("2016: " + Array(12).fill(2016).map(getLastDayOfMonth).join(" "))
```

Comment: а что такое fill ?

Comment: @Leks, создал массив из 12 элементов, заполнил его значением 2019, а потом для каждого элемента вызвал функцию `getLastDayOfMonth` (первым аргументом она получила 2019, вторым индекс, а в остальных немного мусора) и сджойнил через пробел.

Comment: ок, спасибо сложно воспринимать сразу такие конструкции